# Why is pgdump only listing one of the three tables that I want data for?

Tags: postgresql, insert, pg-dump

I’m using Postgres 9.5 on Mac Sierra.  I want to output data from three tables so I have done this

```
pg_dump -U mydb --format plain --section data --column-inserts --file "t1.backup" --table “addresses” --table “table1” --table "table2" mydb
```

The order of the table data is listed is important because I don’t get foreign key errors when I re-import it.  However, in the above listing, despite the fact that I can do this in my database

```
localhost:mydb davea$ mydb
psql (9.5.0, server 9.5.1)
Type "help" for help.

mydb=> select count(*) FROM table1;
 count 
-------
 19516
(1 row)
```

When I open my dump file that is generated from the above statements, I have no data for the “table1” or the “addresses” table.  There are only INSERT statements for the “table2” table.  What’s wrong with my dump statement that only one of my tables’ data is getting dumped?

Comment: Use ordinary double quotes. (or no quotes at all, since the table names dont contain mixed-case or special characters)

Comment: Use `"addresses"` not `“addresses”`

Comment: That's just a result of typing my question in an editor.  THe quotes are fine --  besides if you're theory were right, I wouldn't get data for "table2" because of funky quotes, but I do.

Comment: Note `--table “table1” --table "table2"`  for table2 you *do* use the correct quotes. And please dont blame your editor. Throw it away.